# Laptop won't shut down

Tags: laptop, shutdown

I have sluiced down my Dell N5110, then I washed it with distilled water and fortunately it is working.

And of course I have, as I see, one problem: when I shut down my PC, hard disk stops (hard disc light fades), but laptop does not want to turn off, fans are keep blowing and I am forced to shut down manually by pressing power button.

Do someone know what could be wrong? Thanks for your answers.

P.S. The same when I want to restart computer or wake it up.

Comment: You have sluiced down your laptop?  Do you mean you accidentally spilled something in or on the laptop (presumably the keyboard), and then you rinsed it out with distilled water?  Did you disassemble the laptop completely before you started rinsing things?  How long did you allow the laptop to dry for?  What method did you use to dry the laptop?  Water, even distilled, wasn't the best choice for this...

Comment: This question is not clear.  Clarify what happen to your laptop and what you did.

Comment: I poured over tea on my Dell. I have dismantled the computer and cleaned it with distilled water. The main board looks like new.
I tried to turn my computer too early after accident, so I think that something can be went off..?